# Does an OpenVPN client config .ovpn file require ssl keys or can I use a username and password instead?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

My `.ovpn` file looks like:

```
client

dev tun proto tcp remote 1.2.3.4 1194

resolv-retry infinite nobind

persist-key persist-tun

ca [inline] cert [inline] key [inline]

verb 1

keepalive 10 900 inactive 3600 comp-lzo

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ...
-----END CERTIFICATE----- </ca> <cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ...
-----END CERTIFICATE----- </cert> <key>
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- ...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- </key>
```

So instead of this can I use an username and password?

Comment: It would depend on what the OpenVPN server requires... If it requires a certificate and you don't provide one then it won't let you connect...

Answer (score 0):

If you were given this `.ovpn` file, don't change it.  OpenVPN is flexible and you can configure the server to ask for a username/password instead of client certificates, but the server needs to have a matching configuration in place.  If the server is not configured to accept passwords, a username/password won't work.